# I can't install an app made in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, installation, apk

I have not managed to install or debug an app made by me.

1.- I was unable to compile my app so I updated all packages with all the versions on them. That worked.(My app does not have errors anymore.)
2.- I tried to debug it with some virtual devices I created (and deleted several times) and get the error in console(I tried all the answers given to this, like restarting and adding time to the timeout, and all the stuff posted on similar questions):

```
[2014-03-06 09:46:31 - MainActivity] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'android_2.2'
[2014-03-06 09:46:35 - MainActivity] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-03-06 09:46:35 - MainActivity] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-03-06 09:46:54 - MainActivity] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2014-03-06 09:46:54 - MainActivity] Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2)
[2014-03-06 09:46:54 - MainActivity] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-03-06 09:46:54 - MainActivity] Uploading MainActivity.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-03-06 09:46:54 - MainActivity] Installing MainActivity.apk...
[2014-03-06 09:49:02 - MainActivity] Failed to install MainActivity.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-03-06 09:49:02 - MainActivity] (null)
[2014-03-06 09:49:02 - MainActivity] Launch canceled!
```

3.- I tried to push the file to the virtual device, that did not worked.
4.- After that I opted for using a real device. Here is the error:

```
[2014-03-06 10:09:14 - MainActivity] Android Launch!
[2014-03-06 10:09:14 - MainActivity] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-06 10:09:14 - MainActivity] Performing *.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-03-06 10:09:23 - MainActivity] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2014-03-06 10:09:23 - MainActivity] Device API version is 16 (Android 4.1.2)
[2014-03-06 10:09:23 - MainActivity] Uploading MainActivity.apk onto device '****************'
[2014-03-06 10:09:23 - MainActivity] Installing MainActivity.apk...
[2014-03-06 10:09:24 - MainActivity] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2014-03-06 10:09:24 - MainActivity] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-03-06 10:09:24 - MainActivity] Launch canceled!
```

5.- My last resource push the .apk file to real device. The file was transferred ok, but when I try to install it, I get this:

PARSER ERROR
There was a problem parsing the package.

My questions are, What am i doing wrong? or Is there some kind of execution time error, i am not getting?

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!**

In AdnroidManifest what sdk u use

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: I checked and there are not shown those tags. Do I have to add them? and under which tag?

Comment: Yes . Try to create simple android project go to Android Manifest where you can see all stuff that android manifest create for new project and you will see what you need in your android manifest